# How should I configer PHPStorm to work in team development

Tags: version-control, teamcity, phpstorm

We have a remote webserver which contains approximately 15 applications. What is the best way to configure PHPStorm so we can work in a team (3 ~ 4 persons) on those projects. I've looked into TeamCity but it seems a bit overkill for us. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Use git fot this task. We use git and phpstorm and all works great.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you use git? How do you use the trunk, tags and branches? We are going to use VisualSVN so you might have some answers for me.

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow  this will help =) Also you can google "git workflow"